# get an array of dates for the past week in format dd_mm

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to have an array of dates for whole days of the last week, including the current day, for e.g

```
['05/06', '04/06', '03/06', '02/06', '01/06', '31/05', '30/05']
```

(format dd/mm)

how can i do this?

I know there is the Date() object, but other than that I'm stumped.

logic along the lines of:

```
var dates = [];

var today = new Date();

for (var i = 0; i<7; i++){
    var date = today - (i+1);
    dates.push(date);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

So you want an array containing todays date and a further 6 elements, with todays date-1, todays date-2 etc...?

```
var dates = [];
var date = new Date();

for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++){
  var tempDate = new Date();
  tempDate.setDate(date.getDate()-i);
  var str = tempDate.getDate() + "/" + tempDate.getMonth();
  dates.push(str);  
}
console.log(dates);
```

**Output:** `["5/5", "4/5", "3/5", "2/5", "1/5", "31/4", "30/4"]`

---

If you need numbers with leading 0's, try this:

```
var dates = [];
var date = new Date();

for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++){
  var tempDate = new Date();
  tempDate.setDate(date.getDate()-i);
  var str = pad(tempDate.getDate()) + "/" + pad(tempDate.getMonth());
  dates.push(str);  
}
console.log(dates);

function pad(n) {
    return (n < 10) ? ("0" + n) : n;
}
```

**Output:** `["05/05", "04/05", "03/05", "02/05", "01/05", "31/04", "30/04"]`

Answer (score 0):

Check this working sample, where all days are printed out:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/danyu/Tu5R6/6/
```

This is the main logic:

```
for(var i=7;i>0;i--)
{
    tempDate.setDate(tempDate.getDate()-1);
    output+=tempDate+"<br/>";
}
```

Modify it to store those days into your array.